# android: Notification Crash only on Honeycomb 3.2

Tags: android, notifications, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm getting a crash when displaying a notification but only on honeycomb 3.2.

And it is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36502

i've tried to use a different build of the compat library but a lot of functionality was missing and that doesn't seem like a good solution.

Aside from not showing a notification for 3.x are there any known workarounds?

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.setProgress at 
android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatIceCreamSandwich.add(NotificationCompatIceCreamSandwich.java:31) at 
android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplIceCreamSandwich.build(NotificationCompat.java:104) at 
android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.build(NotificationCompat.java:558) at 
MY Code here
```

Comment: In the link you posted, see Comment 2. It provides a link to a patched version of the support library V4 that addresses the issue. Just use that instead.

Comment: as I mentioned, that release is out of date will not do. I'm hoping there is something else I can do.

Comment: The latest version of the Android SDK has a properly fixed version of NotificationCompat. Sorry about that.

Comment: yeah, saw that too. I used Jake Wharton's library in the mean time. thanks :)

Comment: I've tried the latest support v4 library but I still have the same problem.. (test device honeycomb 3.2.1 -htc flyer) anyone also having this problem (or fix ;) )

Comment: Did you try jake wharton's library?